# Error Unable to update the static FcBlanks

Tags: fonts, miktex

After an update with MikTex 2.9 (Windows 7) I have the problem that some fonts are garbled. Running xelatex displays `Unable to update the static FcBlank` and I get the same error with the following command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>fc-cache
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0600
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0601
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0602
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0603
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x06dd
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x070f
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2028
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2029
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfff9
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffa
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffb
```

I already tried to `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats` in MIkTex. Also restarted Windows.

This is how `Section 5` is currently displayed:

[image]

**Edit:**

- I deinstalled MikTex and deleted everything related I could find
  under %appdata%. A reinstallation did not change anything.
- Reset Windows fonts directory and reinstalled the fonts. Problem is still the same.

**Edit  2:**

- I could not solve this problem with MikTex, so I installed [Tex Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: I get this messages too and made a bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2395/, but I have some doubt that they are responsable for your garbled output. Without a minimal example it is difficult to test.

Comment: I got the same problem after updating my MikTeX installation today.

Comment: I updated my MikTeX today and faced the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I do not know, what exactly caused the problem, but running `mpm --admin --update-db --update` today (first of november 2015) yielded in a system which did not throw those errors any more.
Further more a problem using the package `scrhack` also disappeared.